# Использование "codex Speex"

Tags: java

Нужна помощь с работой кодека "Speex". Есть реализация на java, там кодируются данные, получаемые с микрофона и декодируются данные получаемые из сети. Есть шифрование и дешифровка данных, что мне не нужно, а нужно только кодирование и декодирование и повторить это у меня не получается.

Код оригинала который кодирует, шифрует и отправляет в сеть:

```
public void run()
{
    byte buf_speech[] = new byte[320];
    byte buf_bits[] = new byte [1600];
    byte temp_buf_bits[] = new byte [60];
    while(true)
    {    
        int index = 0;
        buf_bits[index++] = ProxyBuffer.SPEECH_PACKET;
        int ii;
        for(ii = 0; ii < 8; ++ii)
        {
            audio_.getTargetLine().read(buf_speech, 0, buf_speech.length);
            if(!speechDetector.speechDetecting(buf_speech, buf_speech.length))
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < buf_speech.length; ++i)
                    buf_speech[i] = 0;                    
            }
            int sizeBytes = CodecOfSpeech.encode(buf_speech, temp_buf_bits);
            buf_bits[index++] = (byte)sizeBytes;
            for(int i = 0; i < sizeBytes; ++i)
            {
                buf_bits[index++] = temp_buf_bits[i];
            }
        }
        buf_bits[index++] = (byte)0xff;


//шифрование
            if(ProxyBuffer.desKey != null)
            {
                byte bufCrypt[] = null;
                try
                {
                    bufCrypt = 
                            ProxyBuffer.desOut.doFinal(buf_bits, 1, index - 1);
                }
                catch(javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    System.exit(-1);
                }
                catch(javax.crypto.BadPaddingException e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    System.exit(-1);
                }                
                for(int i0 = 0; i0 < bufCrypt.length; ++i0)
                {
                    buf_bits[i0 + 1] = bufCrypt[i0];
                }
                index = bufCrypt.length + 1;
            }


        int crc = 0;
        for(int iii = 0; iii < index; ++iii)
        {
            crc += buf_bits[iii];
        }
        buf_bits[index++] = (byte)crc;
        ++countForAlive;
        if((index <= 6 * ii + 2 + 10 + 8) && (countForAlive < 120/ii))
            continue;            
        countForAlive = 0;
        DatagramPacket packet =
                new DatagramPacket(buf_bits, index, address_, port_);
        outComingTraffic += packet.getLength() + 8 + 24;        
        try
        {
            socket_.send(packet);                       
        }
        catch(IOException exc)
        {
            System.out.println("ReadThread" + exc.getMessage());
            continue;
        }
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="test">

         //*/
        /* //Zeroing for test purpose only
        audio_.getTargetLine().read(buf_speech, 0, buf_speech.length);
        int sizeBytes = CodecOfSpeech.encode(buf_speech, temp_buf_bits);
        CodecOfSpeech.decode(temp_buf_bits, sizeBytes, buf_speech);
        for(int ii = 0; ii < buf_speech.length; ++ii)
        {                
            ProxyBuffer.proxyArray[ProxyBuffer.proxyHead++] = buf_speech[ii];
            if(ProxyBuffer.proxyHead >= ProxyBuffer.proxyArray.length)
                ProxyBuffer.proxyHead = 0;
        }
        //*/
    }
}
```

вот моя попытка:

```
public void run()
    {
        mWindow.stopCapture = false;

        mWindow.audioLine.start();

        byte buf_speech[] = new byte[320];
        byte temp_buf_bits[] = new byte[60];
        int index = 0;

        jCodec = new JSpeexCodec();

        try
        {
            mWindow.inBuf[index++] = 1;

            while(!mWindow.stopCapture)
            {    
                int ii;
                for(ii = 0; ii < 8; ++ii)
                {
                    mWindow.audioLine.read(buf_speech, 0, buf_speech.length);
                    if(!speechDetector.speechDetecting(buf_speech, buf_speech.length))
                    {
                        for(int i = 0; i < buf_speech.length; ++i)
                            buf_speech[i] = 0;                    
                    } 

                    int sizeBytes = jCodec.encode(buf_speech, temp_buf_bits);
                    mWindow.inBuf[index++] = (byte)sizeBytes;
                    for(int i = 0; i < sizeBytes; ++i)
                    {
                        mWindow.inBuf[index++] = temp_buf_bits[i];
                    }
                }
            }

            mWindow.inBuf[index++] = (byte)0xff;    

            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() ->
            {
                mWindow.speakBtn.setEnabled(true);
                mWindow.mcBtn.setEnabled(true);
                mWindow.ftm.addFiles(mWindow.mFile);
            });

            if(audioLine != null)
            {
                audioLine.close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Параметры аудио для записи AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 8000, 16, 1, 2, 8000, false

Реализация оригинала для декодирования:

```
public void run()
    {
        byte buf[] = new byte[1600];
        byte speech[] = new byte[320];     
        while(true)
        {
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
            try
            {
                socket_.receive(packet);
            }
            catch(Exception exc)
            {
                continue;
            }
            incominTraffic += packet.getLength() + 8 + 24;
            int index = 0;
            int crc = 0;
            for(int ii = 0; ii < packet.getLength() - 1; ++ii)
                crc += buf[ii];
            if(buf[packet.getLength() - 1] != (byte)crc)
                continue;

            if(buf[0] == ProxyBuffer.CALL_PACKET)
            {
                if(packet.getLength() != 5)
                    continue;
                if((buf[1] != 0x77) || (buf[2] != 0x77) || (buf[3] != 0x77))
                    continue;                
                if(ProxyBuffer.peerAddress == null)
                    ProxyBuffer.peerAddress = packet.getAddress();
                ProxyBuffer.recvCallPacket = true;
                ProxyBuffer.liveConnect = true;

                buf[0] = ProxyBuffer.ACCEPT_CALL;                     
                buf[1] = 0x55;                                              
                buf[2] = 0x55;
                buf[3] = 0x55;
                crc = 0;
                for(int ii = 0; ii < 4; ++ii)
                {
                    crc += buf[ii];                                         
                }
                buf[4] = (byte)crc;
                packet.setData(buf, 0, 5);
                for(int ii = 0; ii < 4; ++ii)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        socket_.send(packet);
                    }
                    catch(IOException exc)
                    {
                        System.out.println("sendException " + exc.getMessage());
                        continue;
                    }                    

                    try
                    {
                        sleep(100);
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException exc)
                    {

                    }
                }
                MainStream.peerPortIP = packet.getPort();
                ProxyBuffer.acceptCall = true;
                continue;
            }

            if(buf[0] == ProxyBuffer.ACCEPT_CALL)
            {
                if(packet.getLength() != 5)
                    continue;
                if((buf[1] != 0x55) || (buf[2] != 0x55) || (buf[3] != 0x55))
                    continue;
                MainStream.peerPortIP = packet.getPort();
                ProxyBuffer.liveConnect = true;
                ProxyBuffer.recvCallPacket = true;
                ProxyBuffer.acceptCall = true;
                continue;
            } 

            if(buf[0] == ProxyBuffer.SPEECH_PACKET)
            {
                ++index;                
                ProxyBuffer.liveConnect = true;

//шифрование
                if(ProxyBuffer.desKey != null)
                {
                    byte tempDeCryptoBuf[] = null;
                    if((packet.getLength() - 2) % 8 != 0)
                        continue;
                    try
                    {
                        tempDeCryptoBuf = ProxyBuffer.desIn.doFinal(buf, 1, packet.getLength() - 2);
                    }
                    catch(javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("IllegalBlockSizeException" + e.getMessage());
                        continue;
                    }
                    catch(javax.crypto.BadPaddingException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("BadPaddingException" + e.getMessage());
                        continue;
                    }
                    if(tempDeCryptoBuf != null)
                        for(int i0 = 0; i0 < tempDeCryptoBuf.length; i0++)
                        {
                            buf[i0 + 1] = tempDeCryptoBuf[i0];
                        }
                    else
                        continue;
                }

                byte temp_buf[];
                while(true){
                    try {                        
                        if(buf[index] != 0xff){
                            if((buf[index] > 60) || (buf[index] < 0))
                                break;                                                            
                            temp_buf = new byte[buf[index++]];

                            for(int ii = 0; ii < temp_buf.length; ++ii)
                                temp_buf[ii] = buf[index++];                            

                            CodecOfSpeech.decode(temp_buf, temp_buf.length, speech);
                            for(int ii = 0; ii < speech.length; ++ii){
                                ProxyBuffer.proxyArray[ProxyBuffer.proxyHead++] = speech[ii];
                                if(ProxyBuffer.proxyHead >= ProxyBuffer.proxyArray.length)
                                   ProxyBuffer.proxyHead = 0; 
                            } 
                        }
                        else break;
                    }
                    catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException exc){
                        System.out.println("IndexOutOfBoundsException " + exc.getMessage());
                        break;
                    }
                    catch(Exception exc){
                        System.out.println("Exception " + exc.getMessage());
                        break;
                    }                            
                }
            }           
        }
    }    
}
```

Моя реализация:

```
public void run()
    {
        byte temp_buf[];
        byte speech[] = new byte[320];
        int index = 0;
        int indArr = 0;
        mWindow.outBuf = new byte[1024000];
        byte[] bufferAudio = new byte[source_line.getBufferSize()];

        source_line.write(mWindow.outBuf, 0, source_line.getBufferSize());

        if(mWindow.inBuf[0] == 1)
        {
            index++;
            while(true){
                try {                        
                    if(mWindow.inBuf[index] != 0xff){
                        if((mWindow.inBuf[index] > 60) ||
                                (mWindow.inBuf[index] < 0))
                            break;                                                            
                        temp_buf = new byte[mWindow.inBuf[index++]];

                        for(int ii = 0; ii < temp_buf.length; ++ii)
                            temp_buf[ii] = mWindow.inBuf[index++];                            

                        jDecode.decode(temp_buf, temp_buf.length, speech);
                        for(int ii = 0; ii < speech.length; ++ii){
                            mWindow.outBuf[indArr++] = speech[ii];
                        }//конец for                           
                    }//конец if
                    else break;
                }//конец try
                catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException exc){
                    System.out.println("IndexOutOfBoundsException " 
                            + exc.getMessage());
                    break;
                }
                catch(Exception exc){
                    System.out.println("Exception " + exc.getMessage());
                    break;
                }                            
            }//конец while
        }

        if(mWindow.outBuf.length >= 0)
        {
            source_line.write(mWindow.outBuf, 0, mWindow.outBuf.length);
        }
        int ind = 0;
        while(true)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 320; i++)
            {
                if(index != ind)
                {
                    bufferAudio[i] = mWindow.outBuf[ind++];
                    if(ind >= mWindow.outBuf.length)
                        ind = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    bufferAudio[i++] = 0;
                    bufferAudio[i] = 0;
                }
            }

            source_line.write(bufferAudio, 0, 320);
        }

        source_line.drain();
        source_line.close();

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() ->
        {
            mWindow.mcBtn.setEnabled(true);
            mWindow.speakBtn.setEnabled(true);
            mWindow.PlayBtn.setEnabled(true);
        });
```

Мой вариант реализации кодирует и декодирует, но что-то не так. Не воспроизводит в нормальном режиме декодированные данные.

Помогите разобраться в чем ошибка.